# How to change my PK in my database from INT Identity to uniqueidentifier

Tags: sql-server

I have a Database (SQL-Server) with many tables and I build an application that requires synchronizing data between two databases, I use SynFramework, but to avoid conflicts with the data, I decided to change all my primary keys to uniqueidentifier. The problem is that I have too many tables and make the change manually take long.
I thank you in advance

Comment: Before you head down this path, please read the following and weigh the pros and cons:  http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/264/guid-vs-int-which-is-better-as-a-primary-key

Comment: I have considered the issue and does not affect the performance. The purpose of using a GUID is for that integrity is not lost in the relations of the tables to make data synchronization between the two databases and to avoid those annoying conflicts.

Comment: Are these columns also the clustered index? If so this absolutely have a major impact on performance. Here is the challenge, you can't change an existing column from an int to a uniqueidentifier when there are existing rows. When you change the datatype of a column an implicit conversion happens and there is no way for that conversion to succeed. You could add a new column and populate it with newid(). Then drop the old column. But you have to consider that you will have to repeat this process and update every other table that has a relationship with the current table.

Comment: What I want to avoid is to repeat the process because they are many tables and would take a long time to do it

Comment: You are asking for a way to quickly change the fundemental structures of all your tables.  There is no quick way.  Roll up your sleeves, and get to work.  When further down the road you run into performance issues, please come back and review the comments.

Comment: What you could consider doing instead, assuming your using auto-increment keys, is to setup the autoincrement keys so that for one database the seed is 0 and the other's is 1 and both increment the key by 2.  That way keys generated in one DB are all even and the other is all odd.  Then both could be merged, as long as you only have two databases.